# Woocommerce filter products by attributes add checkbox

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, filter

I have searched the net and this support forum for the answer but could not get one that is the correct one. WooCommerce default filter product by attribute is working fine, the display types are list and dropdown how can I add a checkbox to the display type. so I can set it to be a dropdown, list or checkbox?

using:
WooCommerce Version 4.1.0
Wordpress Version 5.4.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a few days and no one got back to me, I finally got a plugin that worked for me, 
Advanced AJAX Product Filters for WooCommerce,  By BeRocket the FREE version worked, you get a paid version also.

FREE version link https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-ajax-filters/

hope this helps someone